# Passing value over to next viewController

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am currently writing an app in `Swift` and I implemented all my UI programatically. I would it kind of exhausting, so recently I decided to use `storyboard` but I am stuck with a bug.

When passing over the `mainContext` from the `AppDelegate` to the `FirstViewController`, the value of the `mainContext` is `nil`. In the first place, when I wrote everything programmatically, my code looked like this:

```
        let vc = FirstViewController()
        vc.mainContext = mainContext
        window?.rootViewController = vc
```

But now that I am working with `StoryBoard`, this is not valid anymore because I have to instantiate the view with its ID, like this:

```
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            var vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstView") as! FirstViewController
            vc.mainContext = mainContext
```

But in this case, the context is `nil`. If I don't instantiate the VC like this, my outlets are `nil` and I get this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Does someone know a way to pass my `mainContext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not accessing the rootViewController, you're creating a new  view controller and not doing anything with it, to access the rootViewController replace this

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstView") as! FirstViewController
vc.mainContext = mainContext
```

with

```
if let vc = self.window?.rootViewController as? FirstViewController {
    vc.mainContext = mainContext
}
```